# Align Dropdown Boxes Better Bootstrap ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

cshtml form in ASP.NET MVC 5 which uses Bootstrap. As you can see the dropdown box is not properly aligned with the corresponding label. How do I change the positioning? The code for the dropdown is:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("For which system do you require a password reset?", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="editor-field">
                <select id="SystemName" name="SystemName">
                    <option value="Citrix">Citrix Desktop</option>
                    <option value="MOL">Manager Online</option>
                </select>
           </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your CSS so we can have a look. Specifically the CSS for `form-group`, `control-label col-md-2`, `col-md-10`, and `editor-field`. Also if there is CSS for the `<select>`.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap which I haven't modified.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I added padding of 10px to the col-md-2 css

Comment: If you add `.form-horizontal` to your `<form>` tag, or wrapping container for the form elements, that will apply padding on the `.control-label` class to properly align it with the inputs and selects, etc.

Comment: all the elements are already wrapped in the form horizontal div

Comment: Could you explain your comment further?

Comment: Based on the code provided, there was/is no way for us to know if you've wrapped the form in `.form-horizontal`. When you add the `.form-horizontal` class to your `form`, the `.control-label` will inherit padding via BS's core CSS. Furthermore, the `.form-horizontal` class will right align your labels. Here's a JS fiddle with the labels highlighted. http://jsfiddle.net/7nhqA/

Comment: Also, based on your picture, you can consider applying the `.form-control` class to your `select`, `input` and `textarea`'s. That will also apply more BS styling for you.